# Angular : Retrieve data from front end in unit test

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular and trying to perform certain task which includes retrieving value from div from front end in ts file. The scenario is as follows :-

I have two drop down on front end and one dropdownToggle button. After inserting and opting for desired operation, the content is showed in a span/div. As part of unit test case, I need to check whether value appeared in div or not. Also, to perform other operation, I am saving that value in an array at ***.component.ts file. I have tried several ways to call that array in ***.component.spec.ts (test case file) but unable to achieve so.

It would be great if someone can suggest the possible solution to get this resolve.

Code Snippet

1. Front End

   ```
   <div class="col">
         <div class="btn-group" dropdown >
           <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="peformSearch(searchOp)" [disabled]="loading">Search </button>
           <button  type="button" dropdownToggle class="btn dropdown-toggle " aria-controls="dropdown-split">

           </button>
           <ul id="dropdown-split" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"  aria-labelledby="button-split">
             <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" >Add</a></li>
             <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" >Sub</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </div>

     </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
         <span class="btn" *ngFor="let e of searchTerms" >{{ e.key }}: {{ e.value }}</span>
     </div>
   ```

2 . Test Case File  (***.component.spec.ts)

```
const component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.ngOnInit();
fixture.detectChanges();
const one = component.searchForm.controls['one'];
const two = component.searchForm.controls['two'];              
 // print div or selected value here
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access the elements like

```
// print div or selected value here
const div = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('div.form-group');
console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

it might be helpful to give more specific css-classes to the elements e.g. `search-term-list`

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentName>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentName);
    })

    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.classname-of-the-tag-whose-value-is-to-be-fetched'));

console.log(de);
de.textContent on innerHtml should return the required value.
```

inside test-suite various options are available By.css('.class'), By.id('#id'), By.tagName('div') etc